# How to display the time it was pressed one key after another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a Keylogger with pynput, but I'm racking my brains and I can't find a solution for this that works, how can I display the time that one key was pressed after another?  This is my code:

```
def keylogger(key):                                   
 try:                                                                                  
  key = str(key)                                       
  key = key.replace("'", "")
  for letter in key:
   print(letter)
 except AtributeError:
  print("Special Character!")

with pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=keylogger) as listener:
 listener.join()
```

If I press the `k` key on the keyboard it will be displayed in the terminal, but I want it to show from the letter `k` onwards the time it took to press compared to the previous key, for example, if I press the `m` key later of `k`, I want it to show if I took 5 seconds compared to key k for example.

Comment: to start off, you will have to save the current time, e.g. using `time.time()`. Then you can compare that later on.

Comment: Can you give me an example?  I tried something similar before but I don't think I did it right

Comment: @Mr. T I already edited